# Text field four-sided border with animation

Tags: swift, uitextfield, cabasicanimation

I would like to highlight text field four-side border when user clicked inside and reverting back when user's editing end. To achieve this I have following code snippet inside editingDidBegin function of my text field.

```
func pulseBorderColor() {
    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    pulseAnimation.duration = 0.35
    pulseAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.green.cgColor
    pulseAnimation.toValue = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 180/255, blue: 29/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    pulseAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    pulseAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    nationalIdentityTextField.layer.sublayers![0].add(pulseAnimation,forKey: nil)
}
```

And to revert back my text field color I have following code inside text field editingDidEnd function

```
func reversePulseBorderColor() {
    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    pulseAnimation.duration = 0.35
    pulseAnimation.fromValue = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 180/255, blue: 29/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    pulseAnimation.toValue = UIColor.green.cgColor
    pulseAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    pulseAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    nationalIdentityTextField.layer.sublayers![0].add(pulseAnimation,forKey: nil)
}
```

However, it could't achieve what I want. What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please show your image or gif or video, which type of animation you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set `keyPath` to the layer of the textfield in question rather than in the `CABasicAnimation`
and also you need to set `borderWidth` to atleast 1 for the color to be visible.

And here is what I tried to modify the code above and had it working

```
 func pulseBorderColor() {
        let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: nil)
        pulseAnimation.duration = 0.35
        pulseAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.green.cgColor
        pulseAnimation.toValue = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 180/255, blue: 29/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        pulseAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
        pulseAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        txtInput.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: "borderColor")
    }

 func reversePulseBorderColor() {
        let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: nil)
        pulseAnimation.duration = 0.35
        pulseAnimation.fromValue = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 180/255, blue: 29/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        pulseAnimation.toValue = UIColor.green.cgColor
        pulseAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
        pulseAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:  CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        txtInput.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: "borderColor")
    }
```

to set borderWidth you can do that by setting it in the code like this

```
txtInput.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

or in the User Defined Runtime Attributes in the identity inspector.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to give borderWidth to my text field, now it is working thank you very much.